# Why are sulphide salts of p and d block coloured?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, color

I have studied that sulphide salts of s block are colourless while p and d block salts are coloured.

But colour intensity of a salt is directly proportional to polarisation in salt.

And s block cations being smaller offer more polarisation. According to this logic, s block salts should be coloured.

Is my knowledge incomplete? Or am I using wrong logic?

Comment: Polarisation and colour are not related. Well, at least not directly.

Comment: [sodium sulfide](https://www.google.com/search?q=sodium+sulphide&hl=en&sxsrf=ALeKk00RRxDv6Os70FOSaTt1BsF422K94Q:1589360778790&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4zo6lvrDpAhUhg-YKHUoXCw0Q_AUoAXoECBkQAw&biw=1366&bih=657) is yellow.

Comment: Pure sodium sulfide is colorless. I do have a bottle of $\ce{Na2S·9H2O}$ in my collection. Technical sodium sulfide is yellow because of the presence of sulfur as impurities. And this impurity of often produced by atmospheric oxidation releasing $\ce{Na2O}$ and free sulfur. Then free sulfur reacts with $\ce{Na2S}$ to produce disulfide $\ce{Na2S2}$ which contains the ion $\ce{S^{2-}}$ which is yellow, the same yellow color as in pyrite $\ce{FeS2}$
 –

Comment: "But colour intensity of a salt is directly proportional to polarisation in salt." This is a  false premise.

Comment: Color of a salt is mainly due electronic transitions, MLCT, LMCT in transition metal complexes. Also convergence of HOMO-LUMO gap leads to easier excitations, small HOMO-LUMO gap make π electrons mobile, since it is easy for the electron to jump to a higher energy level that is close in energy. "Higher polarisation" in salts definitely lead to decrease in HOMO-LUMO gap. But polarization in group 1 salts is not so well due to large size of cations.

Comment: See the answer of this question: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/138309/the-color-of-the-most-sulfides-of-p-and-d-block-elements